# Once I hit an exception, can I ignore all lines below and go to another item in for loop?

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to use two Google API calls to get a restaurant's `price_level` and phone number.

First, looping through

```
for restaurant in name:
    find_place_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?"

    # use separate parameter dictionary b.c. findplace and findplacedetail have diff field.
    find_place_param ={}
    find_place_param["input"] = restaurant
    find_place_param["inputtype"] = "textquery"
    find_place_param["key"] = google_key

    # get place_id then use it to get phone number
    a = requests.get(find_place_url, parameters).json()
```

this is first findplace api used to grab `place_id` for given restaurant. It will look like:

```
{'candidates': [{'place_id': 'ChIJdTDCTdT4cUgRqxush2XhgnQ'}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

if given restaurant has proper `place_id` or else it will give:

```
{'candidates': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}
```

now this is all of my code: from here I grab `place_id` however put it in try and except because as stated above status is either zero or ok. But even if I go pass except it will run find_place_detail api call which requires place_id thus it fails. How can I skip last block of code if I do not receive place_id?

```
price_level2 = []
phone_number = []
for restaurant in name:
    find_place_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?"

    # use separate parameter dictionary b.c. findplace and findplacedetail have diff field.
    find_place_param ={}
    find_place_param["input"] = restaurant
    find_place_param["inputtype"] = "textquery"
    find_place_param["key"] = google_key

    # get place_id then use it to get phone number
    a = requests.get(find_place_url, parameters).json()
    print(a)
    # adding it to original parameter. since only this and findplace parameter has to be different.
    try:
        parameters["place_id"] = a["candidates"][0]["place_id"]
    except:
        print("Phone number not available")
        phone_number.append(None)

    # passing in fields of our interest
    parameters["fields"] = "name,price_level,formatted_phone_number"
    find_place_detail_url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"
    b = requests.get(find_place_detail_url, parameters).json()
    phone_number.append(b["result"]["formatted_phone_number"])
    price_level2.append(b["result"]['price_level'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `else` clause:

```
try:
    parameters["place_id"] = a["candidates"][0]["place_id"]
except KeyError:
    print("Phone number not available")
    phone_number.append(None)
else:
    parameters["fields"] = "name,price_level,formatted_phone_number"
    find_place_detail_url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"
    b = requests.get(find_place_detail_url, parameters).json()
    ...
```

Also, your `except` clause should be more specific (I guess the case you're trying to catch is a `KeyError`). For more information on exception handling in Python, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: oh so if I get an error it will return to for loop? and else: is ran only when try: is accepted?

Comment: Yes, the `else` is only executed if `try` runs without exceptions